# Order dimension vs topological dimension of a poset

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set (poset). We define the *ordering dimension* $\textrm{dim}_\textrm{ord}(P)$ of $(P,\leq)$ to be the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exist a set of linear orders $\mathcal{L}$ on $P$ with $|\mathcal{L}|=\kappa$ such that the ordering relation $\leq$ equals $\bigcap \mathcal{L}$. (It follows from Szpilrajn's theorem that the intersection of the collection of all linear orders extending $\leq$ equals $\leq$, so $\kappa$ is well-defined.)

Now the poset $(P,\leq)$ can be endowed with the interval topology $\tau_i(P)$, which is generated by the subbasis $$\{P\setminus \downarrow x: x\in P\} \cup \{P\setminus \uparrow x: x\in P\},$$ where $\downarrow x := \{p\in P: p\leq x\}$ and similarly for $\uparrow x$.

We denote the [Lebesgue covering dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) $(P,\tau_i(P))$ by $\textrm{dim}_L(P)$.

Is there a poset $(P,\leq)$ such that $\textrm{dim}_\textrm{ord}(P) < \textrm{dim}_L(P)$?

Comment: I think that you need sharp inequality in your definition of the sub-base of the interval topology (or else your interval topology would be discrete).

Comment: For a finite poset the topology is discrete, isn't it? So the topological dimension is zero, but the order dimension can be any natural number. So your question is whether the topological dimension can ever exceed the order dimension.

Comment: @bof that's correct - will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think they are related?  They seem wildly different.  Note that a totally ordered set (such as $\omega_1$) can have uncountable covering dimension.

Comment: @EricWofsey Since the interval topology $\tau_i(P)$, the covering dimension, and the order dimension all come from the same source (the ordering $\leq$), I was hoping that the two notions of dimension are somehow connected. Your example seems to destroy my hope -- but it's of course a useful answer - thanks!

Comment: The question is meaningless since all your interval topologies are discrete. *** Left (or right) topologies make sense, where lower (upper) closed half-spaces form the basis (here *closed* means that $x$ is included in the sub-base set). But, once again, studying the interval topology defined as in the ***Question*** makes no sense, it always--but for the empty space--has topological dimension $0$ (if not for the democratic spirit I would suggest to the moderators to close this question in its present formulation).

Comment: Usually the interval topology on a poset $P$ is generated by the subbase $\{P\setminus{\uparrow}x:x\in P\}\cup\{P\setminus{\downarrow}x:x\in P\}$

Comment: It seems that the dimension $dim_{ord}(P)$ can be equivalently defined as a smallest number of linearly ordered sets whose product contains an isomorphic copy of the poset $P$. So, the problem reduces to studying the dimension properties of finite products of linearly ordered spaces.

Comment: @TarasBanakh You are completely right, I will correct the post

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen It seems that the equality $dim_{L}(P)\le dim_{ord}(P)$ should follow (at least for topologhically nice posets $P$) from the characterization of the covering dimension in terms of $\mathcal E$-mappings to polyhedra, see Exercise 3.2.K in Engelking's book "Theory of Dimensions, finite and infinite".

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thanks for this hint! I had the feeling (but in math this is sometimes not worth much) that this would be the case, so I was looking for the strict version of the inequality

Comment: *Szpilrajn* was the pre-WWII name of this mathematician. Since WWII his name became *Marczewski*. Perhaps *Edward Szpilrajn-Marczewski* could be a happy compromise.